# Does 6 month ubuntu one promotion automatically renew?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I bought a song from ubuntu one music store to benefit from the 6 months free promotion.

Will this automatically renew after the 6 months?

Darryl

Answer (score 2):

From [Ubuntu One Music Streaming](https://one.ubuntu.com/music/player/no-sub/):

> The subscription will automatically stop after 6 months, unless you
>   choose to renew it for $3.99 a month or $39.99 a year.

So the answer is "no", it will not automatically renew after the 6 month period.